# DFS + memo: How can I analyze the time and space complexity

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o, depth-first-search

I have been grinding leetcode and I encountered this question [Frog Jump](https://leetcode.com/problems/frog-jump/) and I solved it using DFS + memo written in JavaScript

Without memo the solution is

```js
var canCross = function(stones) {
    const recurse = (index, jumpSize) => {
        if(index === stones.length - 1) return true
        for(let i = index + 1; i < stones.length; i++) {
            const gap = stones[i] - stones[index]
            if(gap >= jumpSize - 1 && gap <= jumpSize + 1) {
                if(recurse(i, gap)) return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    return recurse(0, 0)
};
```

And this times out of course since its time complexity is O(3<sup>n</sup>). So I use a map to cache the calculated result.

```js
var canCross = function (stones) {
  const DELIMITER = '#'
  const cache = new Map()
  const recurse = (index, jumpSize) => {
    if (index === stones.length - 1) return true
    const key = `${index}${DELIMITER}${jumpSize}`
    if (cache.has(key)) return cache.get(key)
    for (let i = index + 1; i < stones.length; i++) {
      const gap = stones[i] - stones[index]
      if (gap >= jumpSize - 1 && gap <= jumpSize + 1) {
        if (recurse(i, gap)) {
          cache.set(key, true)
          return true
        }
      }
    }
    cache.set(key, false)
    return false
  }

  return recurse(0, 0)
}
```

And this solution passed. But I am having a hard time thinking about the time and space complexity for this solution. I know I can draw out the entire recursion tree and see how the number of nodes grow according to the input size. But I guess that is not going to be a perfect answer during an interview.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

The upper bound of your algorithm is O(n<sup>2.5</sup>).

## Long Answer

For each `canCross()` function call, you either immediately return a value from the cache, or you do a `for-loop` to initiate recursive calls to get the result:

```
   ...
   if (recurse(i, gap)) {
      cache.set(key, true)
      return true
   }
   ...
```

In the worst case (`recurse(i, gap)` is always `false`), for a given key (if not cached), you have to perform a `for-loop` that has a linear complexity. In turn, your key consists of an index and a jump size. That means you will have to do at least `n` method calls for a fixed jump size to cache the results. This is O(n<sup>2</sup>). That's not it, however. Jump size is also variable, but it's likely to never `n/2`, and that means there are no more than sqrt(n) jump sizes to be cached. So, the worst time complexity is O(n<sup>2.5</sup>). It feels that it may even be O(n<sup>2</sup>) because a full `for-loop` will be run only for a small fraction of all method calls, but I don't know how to prove it.

Since the map is likely to have up to n<sup>1.5</sup> unique keys, the space complexity is O(n<sup>1.5</sup>).